# Tagging the first entry for each user in a db entity without querying

Tags: java, mongodb

I have a db entity which creates a record an event for each login. Now i want to tag the first event of a user with FIRST_LOGIN. But i dont want to check in each and every login event if this is a first_login. is there any other way to acheive this ?

Below is the DB(Using mongodb) entity fields for reference:

```
String id;
long creationTime;
long userId;
long startTime;
long endTime;
String loginType; // This is the field i want to update
long loggedOutTime;
```

Comment: Is there any column for login timestamp?Use it order by DESC

Comment: Yes. We have creationTime

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to show a sample document from the collection?

Comment: @chridam I have added the relevant details. I could not figure out how it would be relevant. Kindly throw some light on your thought process.